Combine many tracks into stereo
I bought a background noise track from noises.online some years ago.  My MP3 player malfunctions whenever I play it.  I think it's because I combined many noises into a single WAV file.  According to my internet learning, a WAV file can support many channels, and some electronics don't know how to handle it.
I am feeding the audio from the MP3 player to a prehistoric boom box using a 3.5mm mini-jack.  I think it takes stereo, based on the fact that when I use a mono cable for a single track WAV file, it only comes out of one speaker.
(1) Should I reduce the noises.online file down to two channels?
(2) Would I simply apportion half the channels to a stereo Left channel and the other half of the channels to the stereo Right channel?
(3) I will assume that the signals are of comparable AC energy (RMS power), or from a random variable perspective, comparable variance.  Therefore, to keep to variance of a summed signal from getting too large, I will just divide the sum by square root of N, where N is the number of summed signals.  Does this seem reasonable?
P.S. I am not an audio "expert", just someone with analytic experience in the distant past.  I just dabble in this for practical reasons, like needing background noise.  I will do combining  in either Octave, Matlab, or Python.

I would recommend reading some of the questions here on positioning in audio space, to help you understand why panning everything either hard left or hard right might not be your best plan.

My usage may be uncommon in that it is noise rather than music.  I was actually thinking about combining them into one channel, then replicating the channel on Left and Right just to eliminate the stereo effect.

Hi. How many channels are there in the WAV file? Does it play elsewhere? In what way does the device "malfunction"? This will probably be closed soon, because as it is now, it seems like a consumer question.

I have to find a free weekend to dive into the Python or Matlab.  It's a big commitment and I'm just scouting out the possibilities now.  So I have yet to analyze the WAV file to see how many tracks, but it is probably in the order of a dozen that I combined.  It was years ago. so I don't know how I combined them.  Probably directly on the noisesonline site.  It plays properly on Windows 10 machines right now.  When the MP3 player plays, it just sounds like hissing.
